# Polynomial Long Division in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, warnings

I'm trying to implement polynomial long division based on polynomials of type int array. Here the highest degree coefficients are at the end. I'm basing my code off of the pseudo code available on Wikipedia:

```
function n / d is
    require d ≠ 0
    q ← 0
    r ← n             // At each step n = d × q + r

    while r ≠ 0 and degree(r) ≥ degree(d) do
        t ← lead(r) / lead(d)       // Divide the leading terms
        q ← q + t
        r ← r − t × d

    return (q, r)
```

Here is my implementation:

```
let poly_divide p1 p2 =
    let n1 = Array.length p1 
    and n2 = Array.length p2 
    and q = zero_pol 
    and r = p1 
    and t = zero_pol in
    while ((Array.length r) >= n2) && (Array.length r != 0)do
        t.(0) <- r.((Array.length r)-1)/p2.(n2-1); 
        q = poly_add (q) (t);
        r = poly_add r (poly_opp(poly_mul (t) (p2)));
    done;
    (q,r)
```

The other functions I'm using here work well as I have tested them separately before.

The warning I'm getting is: Warning 10: this expression should have type unit. on the lines q = poly_add... and r = poly_add...

These are the templates of all of my polynomial functions:

```
type polynomial = int array
val zero_pol : polynomial = [|0|]
val int_monone : int * int -> polynomial = <fun>
val poly_to_string : polynomial -> string = <fun>
val poly_add : polynomial -> polynomial -> polynomial = <fun>
val poly_frac_mul : frac -> polynomial -> frac array = <fun>
val poly_mul : polynomial -> polynomial -> polynomial = <fun>
val poly_opp : polynomial -> polynomial = <fun>
val poly_pow_mul : int -> polynomial -> polynomial = <fun>
```

I'm just starting out with OCaml so I'm quite unsure of what the errors means apart from the ones I've had to debug before.

Updated Code:

```
let poly_divide p1 p2 =
    let n1 = Array.length p1 
    and n2 = Array.length p2 
    and q = ref zero_pol 
    and r = ref p1 
    and t = ref zero_pol in
    while ((Array.length !r) >= n2) && (!r.(0) != 0)do
        !t := Array.make 1 (!r.((Array.length !r)-1))/p2.(n2-1); 
        !q := poly_add (!q) (!t);
        !r := poly_add !r (poly_opp(poly_mul (!t) (p2)));
    done;
    (!q,!r) ;;
```

With the error:

```
        !t := Array.make 1 (!r.((Array.length !r)-1))/p2.(n2-1); 
        ^^
Error: This expression has type polynomial = int array
       but an expression was expected of type 'a ref
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
q = poly_add q t
```

is testing for the equality between `q` and `poly_add q t`, it is not an assignment and the compiler is warning you that you are ignoring the result of this test. You are also misunderstanding your pseudo-code: `t` is supposed to be a polynomial of degree `degree r - degree d`.

You need to use references, or transform your while loop into a recursive function.

Similarly, since `r` is an array, whose length cannot be changed:

```
  while ((Array.length r) >= n2) && (Array.length r != 0)do
```

This test does not change during the loop. Structural inequality is `<>`.

Another issue is that this line

```
 t.(0) <- r.((Array.length r)-1)/p2.(n2-1)
```

is mutating your zero polynomial which is a bad idea.

Overall, it is not clear if your polynomial are supposed to be mutable or not.
If they are not supposed to be mutable, you should avoid `a.( ) <-`  altogether.

Comment: I think they are supposed to mutable in this case, so I think I will try to convert them into references first. In that case if I use q := that becomes an assignment correct?

Comment: If the polynomial are supposed to be mutable (aka anyone can mutate the content of the polynomial), then you cannot expose a zero polynomial (you can have a zero polynomial generator: unit -> polynomial), and you need a copy function. Note that having mutable polynomial is not related to having a mutable reference to a (mutable or not) polynomial. And yes, reference assignment is `:=`.

Comment: Hmm okay I misunderstood what you meant. I meant they will be mutable inside the function, so they need to be passed as references. I changed my code but now in this line:

!t := Array.make 1 (!r.((Array.length !r)-1))/p2.(n2-1); 

I get the error: Error: This expression has type polynomial = int array
       but an expression was expected of type 'a ref but t = ref zero_pol so I don't understand where its coming from. I've added the new code in my question

Comment: Sorry I just read that I misunderstood what t was itself, I'm working on that now :)

Comment: hello again @octachron , I have tried but I don't understand how to implement t. My code is currently at the same state as in the update, how would you implement "t" or generally how would you implement the pseudocode with my polynomial functions?